# Fatal error on PDOStatement::execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am learning how to use PDO, but I've ran into this problem very early on. The code terminates with the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function execute()

even though I call in on the prepared object. I've tried several different approaches, but maybe there is something wrong with the SQL code itself, i am clueless.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `weather` ( `text`, `date`, `mc`, `mf`, `fc`, `ff`) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$data = array($text,$date,$mc,$mf,$fc,$ff);
$query–>execute($data);
```

Comment: You do not error detection and handling _at all_ here...

Comment: This is not a real question as nowhere in the code can be seen a call to a function execute()

Comment: You cannot use bindParam with an array. You might use `?` as a placeholder, and bind the array in execute().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function execute()

This error is strange, because `PDOStatement` has not functions, but methods. So the problem is that php interpret `execute` as separated from `$query`.

Why?

Due to a typo: your `–>` is not `->`. See the two dashes enlarged and you will find the difference:

### –

### -

Replace it with a regular dash and it will work:

```
$query->execute();
#     ↑
```